# The major product of the following reaction

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

[image: 1,2-Dibromobutane]

Here,1,2-dibromobutane is reacted with
i) alc. $\ce{KOH}$  
ii) $\ce{NaNH2}$ in liq. $\ce{NH3}$


According to me, since alc. $\ce{KOH}$ causes dehydrohalogenation, using Saytzeff's rule the product obtained after reaction (i) should be one of the either:
[image]
[image: ![enter image description here]


And after reaction (ii), since $\ce{NH2-}$ is a strong base, an E2 reaction proceeds and again using Saytzeff's rule the final product should be:
[image: ![enter image description here]


However, according to the answer key the final product obtained is given as:
[image: ![enter image description here]


Can someone help by explaining where and how I went wrong in my attempt to solve the question?

Comment: An allylic bromide will react with KOH. What happens to terminal alkynes in the presence of NaNH2? Check pKa's!

Comment: Hey, all of your compounds except the first one are wrong as they have 5 carbons.

Comment: @AnubhabDas Yeah sorry, I've corrected them now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you form the allene, the methylene hydrogen has enhanced acidity because deprotonating it leads to a carbanion in which the negative charge is delocalized:

$\ce{CH3-CH=C=CH2} - \ce{H^+ -> CH3-CH=C=\overset{-}{C}H <-> CH3-\overset{-}{C}H-C#CH}$

The proton then reattaches to the opposite end of the allene chain to form a more stable product.  In effect this is a (strong) base catalyzed tautomerization.

Comment: Thanks @zhe.  How to get my resonance structures lined up properly?

Comment: Honestly, I'm not the best person to ask. I liked you what did you with $\equiv$, and that might be the best approach here. @OscarLanzi

Comment: Ok, but the equivalence sign did not really work.  The software put a line break into the contributing structure, which is bad, and I gave up.

Comment: @OscarLanzi For a triple bond `mhchem` uses `#` symbol, and yes, it looks somewhat misaligned and I guess one should just accept it. I also tried to improve the location of the negative charge on carbons with `\overset{...}{...}` so that it doesn't distance hydrogens away.

Comment: Thanks @OscarLanzi, but since the methylene H of the allene is acidic, shouldn't it react with NaNH2 instead of undergoing tautomerisation? And another thing, are alkynes, in general, more stable compared to allenes?

Comment: @asterix [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propadiene) reports that in the parent compounds the equilibrium constant for converting methylacetylene to propadiene is less than $1$ and drops with lower temperature.  This shows that the alkyne is dominant and its formation from the allene isomer/tautomer is exothermic.

Comment: alkynes are of lower E than allenes. It might be questionable if allenes are formed at all in the reaction. Also allenes and alkynes are linear not angled molecules. Texts and web articles on this topic seem very inconclusive. If one is truly interested a trip to the library is in order.